# How to access url variable using Slim3 and Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, slim

I'm trying to get the hang of using Eloquent ORM so I'm creating a simple blog from scratch using Slim3/Twig. I've been successful in creating a User model and Post model that are linked to two tables(user table, post table) and have been able to insert blog post links dynamically into my 'home' twig template.

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StoryListController extends Controller
{
  public function index($request, $response)
  {
    $posts = Post::join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->get();

    return $this->container->view->render($response, 'home.twig', [
      'posts' => $posts
    ]);
  }
}
```

[Simple Blog list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESGrC.png)

I've passed in a variable in to my routes so I can click on a blog post and have it render the view that corresponds with the right 'id'

```
$app->get('/', 'StoryListController:index')->setName('home');

$app->get('/stories/story/{postId}', 'StoryTemplateController:story')->setName('stories.story');
```

but for the life of me I haven't been able to correctly access that variable in my controller.  This is what I've tried, not sure if I was heading in the right direction.  Any help to get me going again is appreciated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StoryTemplateController extends Controller
{
  public function story($request, $response, $postId)
  {
    $post = Post::join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('posts.id', '=', '{postId}')->with(['postId' => $postId])->get();
    return $this->container->view->render($response, '/stories/story.twig', [
      'post' => $post
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the `postId` from the `Request`'s attribute:

```
$postId = $request->getAttribute('postId');
```

or by looking at the array of `$args` which is the third parameter passed to your route action:

```
$postid = $args['postId'];
```

Try this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StoryTemplateController extends Controller
{
  public function story($request, $response, $args)
  {
    $postId = $requst->getAttribute('postId');
    // or $postId = $args['postId'];

    // rest of method
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on!  I had a feeling I was over complicating things.  I was then able to use `$post = Post::findOrFail($postId);` to pull in my $post variable into my template.

Comment: @RobAllen-I've been able to render the 'home' view with my two blog posts and can now click on a post to render the 'story' view, however it seems to only be pulling the first record whether clicking on blog post 1 or blog post 2.  `public function story($request, $response, $args)
  {
    $postId = $request->getAttribute('postId');

    $post = Post::join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('posts.id', $postId)->findOrFail($postId);

    return $this->container->view->render($response, '/stories/story.twig', [
      'post' => $post
    ]);
  }`

Comment: It might just be an issue of me not inserting into the twig template correctly since I'm able to see both posts by using the url /1 and /2 but the 'home' links seem to only point to /1 `{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
      <h2><a href="{{ path_for('stories.story', {'postId': post.id}) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>{{ post.body[:50] }}</p>
      <div class="author">
        By {{ post.first_name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}`